# How to design RESTful API for response object properties dependent on request parameter

Tags: java, rest, api-design, json

I have a RESTful service where clients provide product codes, start date and end date. In response, the service returns a list of price metrics for the products over the date range. Start date is optional. If not provided, price metrics for standard periods are returned.

The data is captured in `PriceMetricsDto` objects and formatted & returned to the client as JSON:

```
@Builder
@Data
public class PriceMetricsDto{

    private String productCode;
    private String productClass;
    private String productFee;
    private String currency;
    
    //has a value only when start date provided
    private BigDecimal customAnnualAverage;

    //these properties are null when start date is provided
    private BigDecimal threeYearAnnualAverage;
    private BigDecimal fiveYearAnnualAverage;
    private BigDecimal tenYearAnnualAverage;
    private BigDecimal fifteenYearAnnualAverage;
    private BigDecimal twentyYearAnnualAverage;

    //has a value only when start date provided     
    private BigDecimal customTotal;

    //these properties are null when start date is provided
    private BigDecimal sixMonthTotal;
    private BigDecimal oneYearTotal;    
    private BigDecimal threeYearTotal;
    private BigDecimal fiveYearTotal;
    private BigDecimal tenYearTotal;
    private BigDecimal fifteenYearTotal;
    private BigDecimal twentyYearTotal;

}
```

`customAnnualAverage` and `customTotal` have a value only when start date is provided. (Note: if no product codes are specified, all products are returned) For example,

```
http://localhost/priceMetrics?startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2021-02-28
```

All of the xxxx`AnnualAverage` properties have a value only when no start date is provided. For exmaple,

```
http://localhost/priceMetrics?endDate=2021-02-28
```

Does this follow the standard way for building a RESTful API under this type of scenario (i.e. optional param dictating population of certain properties)? Or should I break into two domain objects, `PriceMetricCustomDateDto` and `PriceMetricStandardDateDto` with different REST endpoints? For example:

```
http://localhost/priceMetricsCustomDate?startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2021-02-28
```

and

```
http://localhost/priceMetricsStandardDatePeriods?endDate=2021-02-28
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this follow the standard way for building a RESTful API under this type of scenario

Yup, that's fine.  As far as [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is concerned, if the identifiers are different, then the resources are different.  REST does not imply that two resources with similar identifiers will have similar representations.

```
http://localhost/priceMetrics?startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2021-02-28
http://localhost/priceMetrics?endDate=2021-02-28
```

These identify two *different* [resources](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1), and there's no particular reason to assume that the resources are similar.

There's no coupling between identifiers and message schemas (hint: URL shorteners *work*).

Comment: The two resources you listed are the same resource, just with start date query parameter missing.

Comment: No.  They are different resources, that might just happen to have overlapping implementations.  See https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm , https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234, etc.

The identifier includes the query part.  See: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986

Comment: Query parameters are called query parameters, because they query the resources. Am I missing something? They help you filter the representation on a certain path, not define the output by their presence or absence.

Comment: Yes, you are missing something.  See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that, what I don't agree with is that the presence of query parameters dictates representation.

Comment: Note: My second comment was messy. What I mean to say was "They help you filter the resources, not define representation by merely being present or absent"

Comment: "These identify two different resources, and there's no particular reason to assume that the resources are similar." They do identify two different resources, but there is every reason to assume they are similar, because they are in the same hierarchy. They might not be price metrics. Could be users or cars or papers, but definitely similar.

Comment: I agree that's what you meant; but it isn't correct.  `/A` , `/A/B`, `/A?B` identify three different resources; they could be similar to each other, or completely unrelated.  The spellings used for the identifiers don't tell you anything about the semantics of the resource or the representations that will be returned.

Comment: Expressed another way: "human beings should be able to understand resource semantics from the identifier" is not a requirement or a REST constraint (can still be a really good idea for other reasons).

Comment: Then what is the point of having hierarchical and non hierarchical parameters/components of the URI?

Comment: Relative resolution - see RFC 3986

Comment: Did you write the RFC or does your name hold true? Sorry, have to ask this... My brain is melting trying to comprehend this insanity :D

Comment: Is this http://localhost/priceMetrics?endDate=2021-02-28 a different resource from http://localhost/priceMetrics?endDate=2021-10-10?

Comment: Yes, those are two different resources.

Comment: If they are, then no matter the URI, you cannot assume that the resources are similar, but RFC 3986 talks about hierarchical path as a means of defining that "outher things" have the same inner things. So /B is always semantically the same, no matter if you put /A in front or am I wrong? Also, query parameters are used in context of the path parameters, so given /A?B&C and /A?B - B should have the same semantic meaning.

Comment: RFC 3986 defines generic URIs. In an analogy, it defines a programming language and the use of that language is defined by domain specific rules and conventions. While the example here may fulfill the URI specification it definitely violates REST conventions. https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

Comment: @BlažMrak if you were right, then you would have been answered your question **no, there's no way to make this in a RESTful way because that would defeat REST principles**. To be fair, both URIs are different and it might result in different resources. Or at least, result in different representations of the same resource. Semantically is cumbersome of course, "I'm asking for B and I got a hybrid..". Note that what you are trying to do has been solved with GrpahQL, So if defeating REST principles is a problem, you can leave it and adopt GraphQL

Comment: The truth is that given those two URIs you will return the same, a list of different lengths but of the same resource (representation). You do this for convenience or practicality, not for any rule written in stone. Sometimes, that's is counterproductive. Think in those endless lists of huge objects devouring your bandwidth. Why would not you allow clients to fetch a reduced version of the object and then give a URI to fetch'em completely? More or less what you do if you implement HATEOAS.

Comment: @Laiv You can easily do that with a query parameter fields=field1,field2 for example. What I am saying is that the query parameters help you filter and define the representation. With HATEOAS you would fetch reduced version by going to different hierarchy, not by defining or not defining a query parameter. The interpretation of the author stretches the URI definition to the point of breaking basically. It is the same as putting a baby in the microwave and saying that the instructions did not forbid that, when instructions say that whatever you put in, it will cook.

Comment: The hierarchical representation has semantic meaning. To say that /A/B and /B cannot be expected to be similar is an intentional misinterpretation of the URI. Also the same query parameters in the same hierarchical context have the same semantic meaning. To say otherwise is again like saying that the REST does not explicitly define that, the same way jumping of a huge bridge is probably not explicitly forbidden by law, but it doesn't take a genius to figure out that it is a bad idea... It is just intellectually dishonest.

Comment: @BlažMrak *All* semantics of REST (in the original Fielding kind) is carried by Media Types. URIs, including query parameters, must not mean anything to the client. Clients are supposed to follow links and use forms, URIs should be therefore completely opaque. The server is free to define a hierarchy for its own reasons, but it is entirely up to the server and should be of no concern to the client. VoU is spot on.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam like I said, designing the API in this way is not a good thing. I'm a bit fed up with the "read the specs", "should not be a concern of the client" and similar type arguments. The design of the API, that returns different representations implicitly is straight up bad and a stretch of the URI beyond what they were intended for. It is the same reason you strive for explicit function naming. If you have a code base that has eg. getUser(id) and this method deletes the user, it is not a good code.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam it goes the same with the API. "Client should not concern itself with the API", we are not talking about clients. We are talking the user of the API, which is in this case a dev. When you come back to this endpoint 6 months later, you will have no idea, what the endpoint even does, and what it does not do. Let's then add another rule, like if either date is 2021-06-18, return the user's birthday. It does not violate the REST spec, the same way as getUser from above does not violate language syntax...

Comment: @BlažMrak I get where you're coming from, I'm forced to build such APIs for clients. If you're hardcoding all URIs into the client, you (as a dev) sort-of have to understand what everything does and you'll need a detailed description where everything is. It helps if URIs makes sense there, I agree with you there. However, ironically that _does_ violate REST constraints.  Not just that, but its *more work* and is more fragile. Why would you *implicitly* assign meaning to certain URIs, when the server can just as well *explicitly* give you URIs? I.e. hypermedia.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam I am not talking about hardcoding URIs into the client. I am not even talking about the client. But for the sake of it, let's take the client. I want to filter /A resource with a custom start and end date. How do I do that with REST?

Comment: @BlažMrak How would you do that as a human user on a website? You *navigate* to the appropriate *form* starting at some landing page for the app. You enter the start and end date into the appropriate input field in the form and press "submit". There are no URIs involved, except for the initial one. That is the *only* URI a developer, client or user would need to know or care about.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam How would you do that as a front end developer of the website is my question? If you are a human user of the website, there are never any URIs involved anyway. How would you render the response? And what if your team decides that sixMonthAverage is no longer needed, but a twoYearAverage would be better? Your front end and your back end will both have to change for something that is actually only a front end change really. All because your back end query is not only querying the resources, but deciding about the representation of data based on query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution provided by @blaž-mrak, as it really simple, and allows the front-end to decide what they really want.

However, if you where to actually allow requesting several calculations at once, here is an idea on how to do so:

By the way your code looks, you probably have some logic in your application that looks kind of like (let's call the class containing that logic `Controller`):

```java
PriceMetricsDto dto = new PriceMetricsDto();
if (startDate != null) {
    dto.setCustomAnnualAverage(calculateAnnualAverage(startDate, endDate, productDetails))
    dto.setCustomTotal(calculateTotal(startDate, endDate, productDetails))
} else {
    dto.setThreeYearAnnualAverage(calculateThreeYearAnnualAverage(endDate, productDetails))
    dto.setFiveYearAnnualAverage(calculateFiveYearAnnualAverage(endDate, productDetails))
    dto.setTenYearAnnualAverage(calculateTenYearAnnualAverage(endDate, productDetails))
    dto.setFifteenYearAnnualAverage(calculateFifteenYearAnnualAverage(endDate, productDetails))
    dto.setTwentyYearAnnualAverage(calculateTwentyYearAnnualAverage(endDate, productDetails))

    // Same with totals
}
```

Now, the idea to remove this similar and duplicated code is as follows:

Your DTO could have to collections of `BigDecimal`s, one for averages and another for totals. And those values would be calculated implementing the strategy pattern, and allowing the front-end to decide which values it actually wants.

So, your DTO would be something like:

```java
@Data
public class PriceMetricsDto {
    private String productCode;
    private String productClass;
    private String productFee;
    private String currency;
    
    private EnumMap<PeriodAverageEnum, BigDecimal> periodAverages = new EnumMap<>(PeriodAverageEnum.class);
    private EnumMap<PeriodTotalEnum, BigDecimal> periodTotals = new EnumMap<>(PeriodTotalEnum.class);
}
```

Where `PeriodAverageEnum` and `PeriodTotalEnum` would be as such:

```java
public enum PeriodAverageEnum {
    CUSTON_PERIOD (() -> new CustomAverage()),
    THREE_YEARS (() -> new ThreeYearsAverage()),
    FIVE_YEARS (() -> new FiveYearsAverage()),
    TEN_YEARS (() -> new TenYearsAverage());
//    ...


    private final Supplier<IPeriodAverageStrategy> supplier;

    private PeriodAverageEnum(Supplier<IPeriodAverageStrategy> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public IPeriodAverageStrategy getStrategy() {
        return supplier.get();
    }
}
```

(`PeriodTotalEnum` would be really similar, so I'm going to omit it)
And you would have two interfaces `IPeriodAverageStrategy`  and `IPeriodTotalStrategy`  such as:

```java
public interface IPeriodAverageStrategy {
    BigDecimal calculateAverage(Date startDate, Date endDate, ProductDetails productDetails);
}
```

This way, you would have different strategies for each of the requested values. For example:

```java
public class ThreeYearsAverage implements IPeriodAverageStrategy {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal calculateAverage(Date startDate, Date endDate, ProductDetails producDetails) {
        // do your stuff here
        return calculateAnnualAverage(startDate, endDate, productDetails);
    }
}
```

And last but not least, `Controller` would now have a method such as:

```java
public PriceMetricsDto getPriceMetrics(Date startDate, Date endDate, 
        Set<PeriodAverageEnum> periodAveragesDesired, Set<PeriodTotalEnum> periodTotalsDesired) {
    // Get you product details somewhere...
    ProductDetails productDetails = new ProductDetails();
    // Build your dto with the needed product details...
    PriceMetricsDto dto = new PriceMetricsDto();
    
    EnumMap<PeriodAverageEnum, BigDecimal> periodAvgs = dto.getPeriodAverages();
    for (PeriodAverageEnum periodAvgDesired : periodAveragesDesired) {
        periodAvgs.put(periodAvgDesired, periodAvgDesired.getStrategy().calculateAverage(startDate, endDate, productDetails));
    }
    
    // Note this code is kind of the same as the above. It could be extracted using generics
    EnumMap<PeriodTotalEnum, BigDecimal> periodTotals = dto.getPeriodTotals();
    for (PeriodTotalEnum periodTotalDesired : periodTotalsDesired) {
        periodTotals.put(periodTotalDesired, periodTotalDesired.getStrategy().calculateTotal(startDate, endDate, productDetails));
    }
    
    return dto;
}
```

All this being said, the front-end could now make requests such as:

```
SOME_END_POINT?startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2021-02-28&periodAveragesDesired=CUSTON_PERIOD&periodAveragesDesired=THREE_YEARS
SOME_END_POINT?endDate=2021-02-28&periodTotalsDesired=SIX_MONTHS
...
```

in which the front-end would, with just one request, retrieve all data needed.

If you wanted to further improve this, you could add default values to `periodAveragesDesired` and `periodTotalsDesired`, so the front-end does not need to bother about them unless it really needs something specific.

All this being said, unless this type of solution is absolutely necesary for your use case, the **KISS principle rules**. So I'd follow @blaž-mrak's advice

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble, because you are concerning yourself with the problems of the front end. Create a single endpoint GET /priceMetrics?startDate&endDate, which returns:

```
public class PriceMetricsDto{

    private String productCode;
    private String productClass;
    private String productFee;
    private String currency;

    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
   
    private BigDecimal average;
    private BigDecimal total;
}
```

The front end will either call this endpoint multiple times or you can make startDate and endDate arrays of dates if the client wants more than one total. This batching is an optimization which might not even be needed.

If you decide to process batches, your endpoint will return List and the client will have to arrange them then by the start and end date (which is why I duplicated the fields in the DTO).

Note: even the average is not needed -> the client can calculate it by taking the total and dividing by differenceInDays(endDate, startDate).